# Extractall dates - how to separate single years with RegEx in python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, date, regex-group

I have got some dates included within the test in one of the columns in my dataframe.
for example,

```
sr = pd.Series(['04/20/2009', '04/20/09', '4/20/09', '4/3/09', '6/2008','12/2009','2010'])
```

I want to extract these dates..
and half of my year ends up in the 'month' and 'day' columns.

```
result = sr.str.extractall(r'(?P<month>\d{,2})[/]?(?P<day>\d{,2})[/]?(?P<year>\d{2,4})')
result

      month day year
  match         
0   0   04  20  2009
1   0   04  20  09
2   0   4   20  09
3   0   4   3   09
4   0   6   20  08
5   0   12  20  09
6   0   20  NaN 10
```

how can I fix this?

I can only think of processing "'6/2008','12/2009','2010'" separately from "'04/20/2009', '04/20/09', '4/20/09'", and then appending them.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(sr)` does the wrong conversion for dates?

Comment: In my original dataframe, the dates are included within the text, like: "on 9/27/75 Audit C Score Current"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make the match a bit more specific for the months and days.

As there is always a year, you can make the whole group for the month and day optional.

In that optional group, you can match a month with an optional day.

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?P<month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/(?:(?P<day>3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/)?)?(?P<year>(?:20|19)?\d{2})(?!\S)
```

In parts

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is not a non whitespace char (whitespace boundary to the left)
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?P<month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/` Group *month* followed by `/`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?P<day>3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/` Group *day* followed by `/`
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(?P<year>(?:20|19)?\d{2})` Group *year*, optionally match either 20 or 19 and 2 digits
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert not a non whitespace char directly to the right (whitespace boundary to the right)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ALKML7/1)

Comment: thanks for the link! (?!\S) and (?<!\S) seem complicated for me but I'm trying to read about them!

Comment: @bluetail They are lookaround assertions which mean a whitespace boundary at the left and at the right side. I can add an explanation of the pattern if you want?

Comment: @bluetail No they are assertions which are non consuming. I have added the pattern in parts.

Comment: I see.  'assert not a non whitespace'= 'asset a whitespace',  thank you very much. I really liked how you have separated the digits for month/day.

Comment: @bluetail, you can think of it like that but it is technically not the same as an 'assert is' will expect a whitespace char to be present. This negated versions are also true at the start and end of the string.

Comment: one of the dates turned out to be with the brackets, (5/11/85), grrrr! so it skips that.

Comment: @bluetail There are a few ways to get around that. For example https://regex101.com/r/AO3vVf/1 or  https://regex101.com/r/9vyC9g/1 or https://regex101.com/r/IEbgXF/1 for example

Comment: forth bird, what does the (?<!/) mean ?

Comment: @bluetail That is a negative behind, which asserts that from the current position there can not be a `/` char directly to the left.

Comment: thanks again! I am now trying to add " 5/04/74):" .                                                    what am I missing?  (?<![^\s(\w])(?:(?P<month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[/-](?:(?P<day>3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])[/-])?)?(?P<year>(?:20|19)?\d{2})(?![^\s)])

Comment: @bluetail Not really sure what the data is that you tried. You can use backticks in the commets  to format the data like this `?<![^\s(\w])(?:(?P<month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[/-](?:(?P<day>3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])[/-])?)?(?P<year>(?:20|19)?\d{2})(?![^\s)])` (Or add the data to the regex101 link) This pattern finds that date right? https://regex101.com/r/fY1y1m/1

Comment: that's really odd.. I even included a whole string which it finds fine in the test, but it skips it in the big dataframe!                                                                                       ''PET Scan (DPSH 5/04/74): 1) Marked hypometabolism\n'

Comment: For that data it should work. Are you sure there are no whitespaces or unexpected characters between or around the date format?

Comment: its fine now, I figured it out. :)